# reading constants from input file in julia

Tags: julia

I have an input file with the following structure

INPUT:

```
&indata
run          = 1         ,
in_sswf_rk   = 0         ,
in_sswf_sp   = 200       ,
kount_st     = 150       ,
kount_end    = 150       ,
kappa_C      = 0.12      ,
......
```

How can I read all these parameters in Julia into global constants? I am saying constants because I read that performance-wise it is not a good idea to define global variables, and still I need these values to be accesible from multiple functions. Also, can I give each constant a specific type (float, int)?

I guess in Python I would be using the ConfigParser module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation to get high performance with globals:

```
global kount_st
xnew = kount_st::Int * x
```

But making them `const` might be a better approach anyway. Supposing you've already read all these values into a `Dict`, you could say

```
const run = filecontents["run"]
const in_sswf_rk = filecontents["in_sswf_rk"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for functionality similar to the ConfParser module from Python, you could use a package called `IniFile` from JuliaIO. You can find it [here](https://github.com/JuliaIO/IniFile.jl).

The basic usage goes something like this:

```
using IniFile
a = Inifile()
read(a, "path/to/ini/file")
```

Hope this helps!